# Como hospedar server em roteador local com Express.js no Mac OS X?

Tags: node.js, osx, express.js

Desde que eu comecei a usar Mac nao estou mais conseguindo hospedar um servidor local no meu roteador com Express.

No ubuntu bastava passar o IP do roteador como segundo argumento do `app.listen` e tudo funcionava: **[assim](https://jsfiddle.net/m7wm50fu/)**.

Quando tento rodar o mesmo codigo no Mac OSX recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1129:19)
    at listen (net.js:1172:10)
    at net.js:1270:9
    at dns.js:85:18
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Comment: Experimente desligar o firewall do OSX para ver se é ele que está impedindo o acesso (em System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Firewall).

Comment: Nessa linha do jsFiddle que colocaste esse IP não está em _string_... `app.listen(3000, 168.192.1.1, function(err) {`. Tens isso certo? devia ser `app.listen(3000, '168.192.1.1', function(err) {`

Comment: @Sergio Sim, esta em string. O mesmo codigo funciona no Linux.

Comment: @bfavaretto O firewall esta totalmente desligado.

Comment: O IP do OSX é dinamico ou estático? esse IP que estás a atribuir vem de onde? tens de dar o IP da máquina onde estás.

Comment: @Sergio é o IP estatico do roteador.